# How to browse a query result?

Tags: vbscript

I have a query:

```
sqlPU = "SELECT num_uti FROM myTable WHERE C_IDENT_A = '5'
```

but I didn't know to browse my result.

I try this but it doesn't work

```
req.Open sqlPU, oConn

If Not req.EOF Then 
    Set resultSet = oConn.Execute(sqlPU)
    For Each result In resultSet
        WScript.Echo resultSet.Fields(num_uti).Value
    Next
End if
```

Answer (score 3):

Try restructuring the code like this;

```
Dim oConn, req, sqlPU
'Create connection
Set oConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Call oConn.Open("yourconnectionstring")

'Set query
sqlPU = "SELECT num_uti FROM myTable WHERE C_IDENT_A = '5'"

'Open recordset
Set req = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Call req.Open(sqlPU, oConn)

'Loop the return data
Do While Not req.EOF
  'Output field called num_uti.
  WScript.Echo req.Fields("num_uti").Value
  'Move to next record
  Call req.MoveNext()
Loop
'Clean-up
Call req.Close()
Set req = Nothing

Call oConn.Close()
Set oConn = Nothing
```

The code in the question has a few issues,

- The `sqlPU` query string is missing a string termination character *(`"`)* and will cause a syntax error.
- When you call `.Open()` on a `ADODB.Recordset` it is populated and can be traversed using a `Do` loop and `.MoveNext()` method, the extra `.Execute()` you do is not required and re-runs the same query again. The `.MoveNext()` method tells the `ADODB.Recordset` to move it's pointer 1 record, once it reaches the end the value of `.EOF` will equal `True`. Without `.MoveNext()` the pointer will not move past the end of the file *(EOF)* and the loop will run indefinitely or until the script falls over, neither of which is good.
- Referencing columns using `.Fields()` collection requires either an index *(ordinal numeric value starting from 0)* or a string containing the alias of the column *(in this case `"num_uti"`)*. In the original code the column alias wasn't a string which means VBScript would assume it's a variable called `num_uti` and because `num_uti` is uninitialised it would fail.